# Why does application change from SUBMITTED to FAILED immediately when I ran a HIVE select?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I just ran `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1;`,

Then it failed and FinalState of the Application in WEB is Killed.

Hive logs as follows:

```
2014-11-04 23:06:45,264 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.RMAppImpl: Storing application with id application_1415104634062_0005  
2014-11-04 23:06:45,264 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAuditLogger: USER=root IP=10.20.216.51 OPERATION=Submit Application Request    TARGET=ClientRMService  RESULT=SUCCESS  APPID=application_1415104634062_0005    
2014-11-04 23:06:45,264 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.RMAppImpl: application_1415104634062_0005 State change from NEW to NEW_SAVING    
2014-11-04 23:06:45,264 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.RMStateStore: Storing info for app: application_1415104634062_0005    
2014-11-04 23:06:45,264 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.RMAppImpl: application_1415104634062_0005 State change from NEW_SAVING to SUBMITTED    
2014-11-04 23:06:45,264 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.RMAppImpl: Updating application application_1415104634062_0005 with final state: FAILED    
2014-11-04 23:06:45,264 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.RMAppImpl: application_1415104634062_0005 State change from SUBMITTED to FINAL_SAVING    
2014-11-04 23:06:45,264 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.RMStateStore: Storing info for app: application_1415104634062_0005    
2014-11-04 23:06:45,265 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.RMAppImpl: application_1415104634062_0005 State change from FINAL_SAVING to FAILED    
2014-11-04 23:06:45,265 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler: Couldn't find application application_1415104634062_0005    
2014-11-04 23:06:45,265 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAuditLogger: USER=root OPERATION=Application Finished - Failed TARGET=RMAppManager RESULT=FAILURE  DESCRIPTION=App failed with state: FAILED   PERMISSIONS=Application application_1415104634062_0005 submitted by user root to unknown queue: default APPID=application_1415104634062_0005    
2014-11-04 23:06:45,265 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManager$ApplicationSummary: appId=application_1415104634062_0005,name=select count(*) from tt3(Stage-1),user=root,queue=default,state=FAILED,trackingUrl=N/A,appMasterHost=N/A,startTime=1415113605263,finishTime=1415113605264,finalStatus=FAILED
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it, I set mapreduce.map.memory.mb in mapred-site.xml greater than yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your ram size 
set the Config like this

In yarn-site.xml
This is the total cluster memory

```
<name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
<value>40960</value>

<name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
<value>2048</value>
```

in MapReduce 
set variable mapred-site.xml:

```
<name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
<value>4096</value>
<name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
<value>8192</value>
```